# Cannot run 'uuid-ossp' functions even when it's activated

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, uuid

I want to generate a v4 uuid in PostgreSQL using the [extension uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/uuid-ossp.html), so in `psql` I ran:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

Then I ran `SELECT uuid_generate_v1();` or `SELECT uuid_generate_v4();` but I always get this error:

```
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v1() does not exist
LINE 1: select uuid_generate_v1();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So how can I solve this error?

Comment: What is the output of `show search_path;`?

Comment: from https://postgresql.org/docs/9.4/uuid-ossp.html#AEN170626 Note: If you only need randomly-generated (version 4) UUIDs, consider using the gen_random_uuid() function from the pgcrypto module instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

- you ran `CREATE EXTENSION` in a different database (`postgres`?)
- you installed the extension in a schema that is not on the user's `search_path`.

Use

```
\dx "uuid-ossp"
```

in `psql` to see where the extension is installed.